# Choosing between package:html, dart:html, dart:io (class HttpClient) and package:http APIs to fetch HTTP resources

Tags: android, dart, httprequest, api-design, dart-pub

I realized that currently there are at least three "official" Dart libraries that allow me to perform a HTTP request. What is more, three of those libraries (dart:io (class HttpClient), package:http and dart:html) have each a different, incompatible API.

As of today, package:html does not offer this functionality, but on its GitHub page I found it aims for 100% API compatibility with dart:html, so these methods will be added there eventually.

Which package provides the most future proof and platform independent API to issue a HTTP request in Dart?

Is it package:http?

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

var url = "http://example.com";
http.get(url)
    .then((response) {
  print("Response status: ${response.statusCode}");
  print("Response body: ${response.body}");
});
```

Is it dart:html/package:html?

```
import 'dart:html';

HttpRequest.request('/example.json')
  .then((response) {
      print("Response status: ${response.status}");
      print("Response body: ${response.response}");
});
```

Or dart:io?

```
import 'dart:io';

var client = new HttpClient();
client.getUrl(Uri.parse("http://www.example.com/"))
    .then((HttpClientRequest request) {
      // Optionally set up headers...
      // Optionally write to the request object...
      // Then call close.
      ...
      return request.close();
    })
    .then((HttpClientResponse response) {
      print("Response status: ${response.statusCode}");
      print("Response body:");
      response.transform(UTF8.decoder).listen((contents) {
        print(contents);
      });
    });
```

Let's say I want to cover Android too. That adds package:sky in the mix as well (https://github.com/domokit/sky_sdk/). I admit that this is not "official" Google library.

```
import 'package:sky/framework/net/fetch.dart';

Response response = await fetch('http://example.com');
print(response.bodyAsString());
```

What is (going to be) a regular product is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t8xdEO8LyL8. I wonder what **their** HTTP Request story is going to be. Something tells me it will be yet another different beast from all we have seen so far.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `html` package is a HTML parser which allows to work with HTML server side. I wouldn't expect it to get some HttpRequest capabilities.

The [`http`](https://pub.dev/packages/http) package aims to provide a unified API for client and server Dart code. The API in `dart:html` is only a wrapper over the API the browser provides. The HttpRequest API in `dart:io` was built without browser restrictions and thus deviates from `dart:html`. `package:http` provides an unified API which delegates to `dart:html` when run in the browser and to `dart:io` when run on the server.

I think `package:http` is future proof and cross-platform and should be a good fit for your requirements.

Comment: I wonder why was not the API more unified to begin with. What is the purpose of calling the same thing `statusCode` in `dart:io` and `status` in `dart:html`? The only reason I can come up with is lack of attention. Not something I care to see in a standard library of a language.

Comment: They just didn't want to let the browser implementation dictate how to implement the Dart native implementation. They have no control about how the API evolves in the browser. I think this is reason enough to just do their own thing.

Comment: Well, they are at least working on package:http to unify this stuff now.

Comment: Unfortunately package:http has major bugs still not fixed after 4 years :'(

Comment: ... what bug for example?

Answer (score 0):

https://pub.dev/packages/web

> If you maintain a public Flutter package that uses dart:html or any of the other Dart SDK web libraries, you should migrate to package:web as soon as possible. package:web is replacing dart:html and other web libraries as Dart's web interop solution long-term. Read the package:web vs dart:html section for more information.
>
> https://dart.dev/interop/js-interop/package-web